# In LCD technology what is the “duty cycle” of each pixel

Tags: lcd

I am trying to determine how much energy is transferred from an SLA printer pixel to the resin. One of the key things I am having trouble finding a good answer to is given a static image how long is any given pixel actually on during the display time? Basically what is the “Duty Cycle” of that pixel. I am inclined to think that the duty cycle of each pixel would be would be theoretically 1/(number of rows in the screen). In practice obviously the transistors driving the Row-Column matrixes dont turn off immediately so it would be a little longer. Obviously since the screens are made to display images and this not really there purpose Im having trouble finding much decent technical information on the subject. If anyone has information on the how much energy would be absorbed in LC before it got to the resin that would be bonus.

Comment: I thought pixels in an LCD are always on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to determine how much energy is transferred from an SLA printer pixel to the resin. One of the key things I am having trouble finding a good answer to is given a static image how long is any given pixel actually on during the display time? Basically what is the “Duty Cycle” of that pixel.

The "duty cycle" is nearly 100%, but a lot of energy is still lost in the display due to polarization, fill factor and absorption, especially if using very short wavelengths.

This should really be measured, but a transmission of less than 50% is certainly possible for shorter blue wavelengths even when the pixel is on and the light source polarized. If you're using 405nm or lower, transmission could be even less.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, modern active-matrix LCD panels operate more like DRAMs than any other type of matrix display. See this diagram, copied from [here](https://www.intechopen.com/books/new-developments-in-liquid-crystals/active-matrix-liquid-crystal-displays-operation-electronics-and-analog-circuits-design):

[image: active matrix LCD structure]

As a result, individual pixels are not PWM'd at all, they have a continuous intensity. And in an SLA printer, I would expect them to be either full-on or full-off.

Comment: Thank you so much that source is pretty helpful!